# Списочный подкласс

Tags: python-3.x, list

подскажите как создать списочный подкласс.
Типо того

```
class classA:
   self.attr = List[classB]

class classB:
   self.attr1=1
   self.attr2=2

param = classA.attr[0].attr1
```

Comment: Попробуйте более развёрнуто описать, что вы хотите. Сейчас у вас какой-то совершенно некорректный кусок кода, из которого вообще не понятно, что вам нужно.

Comment: @Xander, есть json, который выглядит так {"attr": [{"attr1": "1", "attr2":"2"}, {"attr1": "3", "attr2":"4"}]} - Как его преобразовать в класс?

Comment: что такое "преобразовать в класс"? как должен выглядеть этот класс? Чего вы хотите добиться?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать SimpleNamespace для представления элементов джсона, и оно будет себя вести именно так, как вы описываете:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

# Ваш исходный json
data = '{"attr": [{"attr1": "1", "attr2":"2"}, {"attr1": "3", "attr2":"4"}]}'

x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))

param = x.attr[0].attr1
print(param)
```